# selecting doesnt seem to work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm building an CMS system on a single page. I use two forms. One to select which page to modify and then the another to modify the content. The problems I'm having now is that in the second form I use a code to select my database entries for this page but this half works.

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='title' value=<?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){echo $rows['Title'];}?> />
    <input type='text' name='inh' value=<?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){echo $rows['inh'];}?> />
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Title outputs the right data but `inh` doesn't. I've checked the database names it should work it's listed `inh` in the database as well.

The value of `inh` outputs "/" No errors just a slash.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You're trying to fetch a  __second__ row and get the inh value from that.... you should only do a fetch for each __row__ not for each __column__; and you only need a `while` loop if you're fetching several rows

Comment: This could have been easily avoided if you took the time to understand what your code actually does.

Comment: Ugh... "CMS System", though not the answer your looking for, for the sake of humanity and my quest against this mistake: CMS = Content Management System, which makes the extra "system" completely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); ?>
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='title' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>' />
    <input type='text' name='inh' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['inh'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>' />
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

[htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) added in case your Title and inh values contain characters (such as quotes) that need to be displayed as HTML entities

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also kept the htmlspecialchars in the code :) this helped alot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$query = "YOUR QUERY";
$SQL = $mysqli->query($query);


while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
<form method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='title' value=<?php echo $rows['Title']; ?> />
<input type='text' name='inh' value=<?php echo $rows['inh']; ?> />
<input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
}

   $mysqli->close();     
?>
```

Try this code this should help you in what your trying to do

Comment: Why revert to mysql_?!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry just noticed he had mysqli instead of mysql my excuses i will edit the code accordingly